# How do I put given data into dictionary?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

So I've got some lines from a website to a variable using json, and the code looks like this:

```
with urllib.request.urlopen("someurl") as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
```

Now, this data contains text like:

> "Dog": "Woof"
>
> "Cat": "Meow"

and so on.. How do I put this data so the Key of the dictionary would be the animal and the value would be the sound?

Comment: If you use `requests`, you can just do `import requests; data = requests.get(url).json()`

Answer (score 2):

json.loads() already did that for you. try accessing data['Dog'] and you will get 'Woof'